# Using docker-compose to set up a nodejs app with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am trying to containerize a nodejs app which uses a mysql database. The nodejs app and the mysql database each resides in their own container. This stack works when I ran it directly without Docker.

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  expose:
    - "3306"
  environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret-root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: web
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: web

app:
  build: .
  container_name: app
  volumes:
    - ".:/app"
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    DB_HOST: db:3306
    DB_USER: web
    DB_PASS: web
    DB_PORT: "3306"
```

The `Dockerfile` for the node app:

```
FROM node:6.10

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm i -g db-migrate

EXPOSE 3000

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

By executing `docker-compose up` the containers have successfully started.

**UPDATE 1**

The node app is then manually started by running `nodejs node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon -L ./bin/start.js` inside the app container.

**UPDATE 1 END**

The app is now listening on port 3000. I am able to connect to the db using a external mysql client.

However, whenever the app tries to query the database, I am getting the following error:

```
/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
    at fromObject (buffer.js:262:9)
    at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:101:10)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:80:17)
    at Object.Auth.token (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js:29:22)
    at Handshake._sendCredentials (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:78:29)
    at Handshake.HandshakeInitializationPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:60:10)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, i might be missing something here. I the CMD, I see only the tail command. where does the node.js program get started? In the CMD, we would say something typical like "CMD ["node", "app.js"]". fYI, this is not answer, but since I dont have the capability to comment, I have put this in answer section.

Comment: Two main points: Where are you running the app? In your Dockerfile you have a CMD statement which uses tail on `/dev/null`, which pretty much does nothing. You need to change it to something like `CMD ["node", "your-app-here.js"]` We can't really help you as we don't know what your source code is, as the error is pretty unhelpful.

Comment: Question updated with explanation for starting the nodejs app. @tcnj